# Apache consuming large memory with Apache Mobile Filter

Tags: apache-2.2

I installed and configured [Apache Mobile Filter](http://wiki.apachemobilefilter.org/index.php/Main_Page) module for Apache to redirect users to mobile version of our website, depending on their user agents. I configured the module to use WURFL.

But as soon as I start Apache it hogs a large amount of memory (without any in-coming web requests):

Resident Memory: 300 to 400 MB
Virtual Memory: 300 to 650 MB

Without this module, Apache was consuming much lesser memory (4 to 10 MB).

What could be the reason here?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am the owner of AMF, AMF stored the Device Repository in memory with several index this is the reason AMF is very fast.

But I don't know why it's take in your webserver so much memory, on my [apachemobilefilter.org](http://www.apachemobilefilter.org) webserver with two repositories (WURFL and 51Degrees) take only 230mb, my virtual server has only 256mb memory.